# Один .java файл с несколькими классами, один .class файл

Tags: java, классы

Интересный вопрос.
Если в файле .java есть два и более классов то джава создат несколько .class файлов.

А при каких условиях будет один .class файл? При том что внутри .java классов несколько

Answer (score 1):

Ни при каких. Для каждого класса всегда создаётся отдельный объектный модуль. Иное невозможно в силу того, что [формат class-файлов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) этого не предполагает:

> Each class file contains the definition of a **single** class or
>   interface.

Comment: Странно. Почему преподаваль говорит что такое бывает? Интересно кто чего не знает. У преподавателя опыта много.

Comment: Все могут ошибаться. И я могу. Поэтому будет здорово, если вы узнаете у опытного преподавателя, как обойти спецификацию, и напишите рецепт здесь.

Comment: Добавил ответ преподавателя.

Comment: Самое время опечалиться качеством получаемого образования.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого джава класса, даже вложенного после компиляции создаётся отдельный файл .class (названию вложенных классов прешествуют несколько спец символов)

Comment: Проверил на практике - нет.

Comment: странно как то ты проверял start$Inner.class

Comment: У меня такого не было

Comment: из папки с проектом по пути out\production\NAMEOFPROJECT

Answer (score 0):

если исключить приколы типа закомментированного класса :) то есть пара псевдо классов - динамические прокси и лямбды которые можно с натяжкой считать "синтактическим подсластителем" анонимных классов. но оба варианта так себе.

```
public class ClsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object proxy = Proxy
            .newProxyInstance(ClsTest.class.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{Runnable.class}, (proxy1, method, args1) -> {
                System.out.println("I'm lambda - actually a synthax sugar for anonymous class, see stack trace: ");
                new Throwable().printStackTrace();

                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println("And I'm old good anonymous class, see my stack trace");
                        new Throwable().printStackTrace();
                    }
                }.run();
                return null;
            });

        System.out.println("I'm dynamic proxy class: " + proxy.getClass());
        ((Runnable)proxy).run();
    }
}
```

Comment: И даже для динамических прокси и лямбд будут сгенерированы отдельные объектные модули, только не будут сохранены в файлы. Если не исправить это ключом `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=.`